# Why does Stack Overflow's help page say the SSL certificate is issued for footballsupport.geniussports.com?

Tags: discussion, ssl

On the [Stack Overflow help page](https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/home) you can see the certificate is issued to a different site.

[image: Certificate]

Both Stack Overflow and that site use freshdesk. 
 Does the certificate from freshdesk need to be updated?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's just the first domain listed on the certificate. Ours is in the alternative names section, along with a list of other domains using Freshdesk. I believe it's some sort of global "custom domains certificate" that Freshdesk uses for multiple clients rather than issuing separate certificates for every single client.

Comment: That does indeed [appear to be the case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvniQ.png)

Comment: It is worth mentioning that SE uses that same feature. The certificate served here on this site is issued to *.stackexchange.com and in the subject alternatives names you'll find stackoverflow.com and *.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to what Animuson said, this is the hallmark of a [UCC certificate](https://www.godaddy.com/help/what-is-a-multiple-domain-ucc-ssl-certificate-3908), where you list all the domains that the certificate is valid for (emphasis mine in quote)

> UCCs are compatible with shared hosting. **However, the site seal and certificate "Issued To" information will only list the primary domain name.** Please note that any secondary hosting accounts will be listed in the certificate as well, so if you do not want sites to appear 'connected' to each other, you should not use this type of certificate.